# Spark avoid partition overwrite

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am writing a Spark Application that saves log data into a directory `/logroot`.

My code is

```
myDF.mode('overwrite').partitionBy('date','site').save('logroot')
```

I want to use the `overwrite` mode in order to re-process many times a week all the daily data.

My concern is that `overwrite` cleans all the `logroot` directory and not only the partitions involved.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You can use append mode and avoid over write. But can you be more elaborate, whats your requirement

Comment: Hi, I've already tried with append mode, the issue is that if, for any reason, I need to reprocess a day (a date+site partition) for which already exists data data sums instead of overwrite.

Comment: Can you please be more elaborate. Would you like to reprocess the output data?

Comment: Let me give you an example: today 2016 06 8 i process data for 2016-06-02, 2016-06-02, ... 2016-06-07. Tomorrow i will restart to process data from 2016-06-03 to 2016-06-08 and so on. If I ll go trough APPEND mode I will obtain 7X data on single days. On the other case with OVERWRITE I will destry every partitioned data present, in this case for instance 2016-06-02 on the secon run. How can I overwrite only a partition?

Comment: So you are getting older partitions also in input.And you want existing partitions to be appended, and new partitions to be created. Did I get you?

Comment: I want existing partition to be owerwritten and the new ones created

Answer (score 1):

At the moment of writing the best solution seems:

- Extract from the initial dataframe the partition names that should be cleaned
- Clean these partitions using hadoop fs api
- Save dataframe using the `append mode`

Thanks to all for the help and hope Spark guys will provide a more elegant solution option.

Roberto